# Issue with bluebird and request to get rest response

Tags: node.js, rest, bluebird

I use 'request' module to request a rest service with the following code :

```
var request = require('request');
request.get('http://localhost:8190/api/1.0/product/012345',
        { auth: { user: 'toto', pass: 'totopass'} },
        function(error,response,body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
```

And it works :)
But I had to ensure that the call is synchronous, so I want to use a promise.
I wrote the code below :

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
request.getAsync('http://localhost:8190/api/1.0/product/012345',
        { auth: { user: 'toto', pass: 'totopass'} }).then(function(error,response,body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
```

But it fails and I see 'undefined' is the console.

Comment: Promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous.

Comment: By default the `then` and `catch` of a Promise are only given a single parameter where the workaround is to bundle multiple parms into a single object or do as suggested in answer

Comment: That's my issue... I really need the response before handling the rest of the processing !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `promisifyAll` by default drops the err argument, and returns only a single argument. Try setting `multiArgs` when promisifying, then using `spread` to pass the resulting array into the next function, and moving error handling into a `catch`, something like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'), {multiArgs: true});

request.getAsync('http://localhost:8190/api/1.0/product/012345',
    { auth: { user: 'toto', pass: 'totopass'} })
.spread(function(response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    })
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```